# Compact-open topology for the space of continuous paths

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

My question is probably silly... There is a cryptic claim in [Hatcher's book](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf) page 530 that I do not understand about the compact-open topology on the set of continuous maps from the segment $[0,1]$ to a topological space $X$. I guess that it is a misunderstanding with the English words.

It is claimed that a basis of open subsets in this particular case consists of the open sets $\bigcap_i M(K_i,U_i)$ where the $K_i$'s are *a partition of $[0,1]$ into nonoverlapping closed intervals*. Consider the open subset $M(\mathbb{K},U)$ where $\mathbb{K}$ is the Cantor set. I do not see how to find an open of the form $\bigcap_i M(K_i,U_i)$ contained in $M(\mathbb{K},U)$, unless the partition is not necessarily finite: in that case, $M(\mathbb{K},U)=\bigcap_{b\in \mathbb{K}} M(\{b\},U) \cap \bigcap_{n\geq 0} M([a_n,b_n],X)$ where the $[a_n,b_n]$ are the closure of all connected components of the complement of $\mathbb{K}$.

> What does Hatcher mean exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Hatcher is claiming something different (emphasis mine):

> In [the case of the compact open topology on $X^I$] one can check that **a system of basic neighborhoods of a path $f: I \to X$** consists of the open sets $\bigcap_i M(K_i, U_i)$ where the $K_i$'s are a partition of $I$ into nonoverlapping closed intervals and...

On the other hand, the subbasis of the topology definitionally consists of the sets $M(K, U)$. A basis of the topology then consists of finite intersections of such sets. (Note that this means there is no "overlapping" condition on the basic open sets.) This means that your open subset $M(\mathbb K, U)$ is already a basic open set.